# How to insert specific dataframe column(s) into databse?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I need to insert a dataframe by column or columns into an SQLite database table. Adding fraction of dataframe columns.

| VendorID | tpep_pickup_datetime | tpep_dropoff_datetime | passenger_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:28:15 | 2020-01-01 00:33:03 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:35:39 | 2020-01-01 00:43:04 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:47:41 | 2020-01-01 00:53:52 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 00:55:23 | 2020-01-01 01:00:14 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 00:01:58 | 2020-01-01 00:04:16 | 1.0 |

I know how to insert only one column. When i insert multiple columns it's not working:

```
crsr = conn.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO vendor (VendorID) VALUES (?)"
# extract column and convert to list of single-value tuples
data = [(x,) for x in df['VendorID']]
crsr.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
```

How to add one or multiple columns from a Pandas dataframe to an SQLite database with for example `tpep_pickup_datetime` and `tpep_dropoff_datetime` ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not do it like this at all. You use the [Panda's to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) feature. For a more detailed answer, you, of course, need to provide a proper question.

Comment: I've corrected it. But the problems is still the same.. I simply dont know how to add few columns to  to sqlite database :)

Comment: You use df.to_sql, as I mentioned

Comment: Yes, ive tried and it's really working wonderful :))